# How to draw borders more finely using open cv

Tags: java, opencv

I get the coordinates of the image based on black.

The resolution of the border was not good, so I redrawn it using open cv. But as shown, the horizontal line protrudes a little, so this part is checked first. How can I draw it neatly?

How to draw a line perfectly without red parts?
[image]

```
 String imageFile = file.toString(); 
         Mat grayImage = Imgcodecs.imread(imageFile, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
         Mat thresholdInverted = new Mat();
         Imgproc.threshold( grayImage, thresholdInverted, 127.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU );
         Imgcodecs.imwrite( "D:\\grayImages\\"+file.getName(), thresholdInverted );
         
         //2. find borders
         List<MatOfPoint> horizontalContours = morphOpenAndFindContours( thresholdInverted, new Size( 20, 1 ));
         List<MatOfPoint> verticalContours = morphOpenAndFindContours( thresholdInverted, new Size( 1, 15 ));  
         //3. draw borders
         this.drawWhiteContours( verticalContours, grayImage );  
         this.drawWhiteContours( horizontalContours, grayImage );



private List<MatOfPoint> morphOpenAndFindContours( Mat img, Size kSize)
{
    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement( Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, kSize );

    Mat openedImage = new Mat();
    Imgproc.morphologyEx( img, openedImage, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, new Point( -1, -1 ), 1 );
    Mat dilateKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement( Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size( 3, 3 ) );

    Imgproc.dilate( openedImage, openedImage, dilateKernel );

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

    Imgproc.findContours( openedImage, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    return contours;
}

private void drawWhiteContours( List<MatOfPoint> contours, Mat image )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
        Imgproc.drawContours( image, contours, i, new Scalar( 0,0,0 ), -1 );//(0,0,0) black line
    }
}
```

[image]
Part of the original image problem

Comment: I modified the thickness of the border line, but it was still not drawn properly.
still sticking out like a red part

    Mat dilateKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement( Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size( 2, 2 ) );// 1, 1

Comment: Did you try checking the endpoint coordinates for those lines? Would they match up nicely if the lines had a 1-pixel thickness?

Comment: Even with 1 pixel, the last part still looks like this

Comment: Just for clarification: you are starting with an existing image that contains lines/cell borders and you want to "paint them over" with yours? I'm no OpenCV expert but in that case I'd try to find the intersection points of the borders and then draw lines between those, i.e. I would not redraw the contour but try to interpret it. How to do that with OpenCV is something I can't tell you, however.

Comment: The existing image has a low resolution, so the intersecting part is displayed in white instead of black, so I try to draw it using open cv

Comment: Could you provide an example of the original image? This might help understand your problem and suggest solutions.